# How to make Django Rest-Framework to respond 401 on a unauthenticated request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the default django authentication, I have this APIView class:

```
class MatchesViewSet(APIView):                                                          

    ...
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    ...

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ...
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

And this test methods:

```
class MainTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):    
        ...                                       
        self.c = Client()
        ...                                      


    def test_only_for_logged_in_users(self):          
        r = self.c.get("/api/matches")                
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 401)
```

The problem is I am getting a HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN while I would like to get a HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/187